# MS SQL use IDENT_CURRENT as variable of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the IDENT_CURRENT of a specific table inside a query I'm writing.

I don't want to do a query to store the ID and another query to use it. I'd like something like:

```
UPDATE my_table1
SET my_column1 = IDENT_CURRENT(my_table2)
WHERE my_column2 = ?
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If concurrent sessions insert into `my_table2` the value of `IDENT_CURRENT` might be completely meaningless.

Comment: I'm getting the `IDENT_CURRENT` of a table I've edited before this query, and then I use this query to assign to the previously generated row all the elements that match the condition. The `IDENT_CURRENT` is an autoincrement

Comment: Yep. That isn't thread safe. You should use the `OUTPUT` clause to get the value that was just inserted.

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` should get the last ID of the session of SQL I'm working with... No?

Comment: No. [See the docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) `Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or view. The last identity value generated can be for **any** session and any scope.`. You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or the `OUTPUT` clause for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs quotes around table name.

```
UPDATE my_table1
SET my_column1 = IDENT_CURRENT('my_table2')
WHERE my_column2 = ?
```

Comment: yes was the quotes the problem, thanks. but it doesn't need the select statment

Comment: Edited for final answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code will work fine.
Table name for the function `IDENT_CURRENT` must be in quotas:

```
UPDATE my_table1
SET my_column1 = IDENT_CURRENT('my_table2')
WHERE my_column2 = ?
```

Comment: Made edit. Try putting table name in quotes on the call to IDENT_CURRENT

Comment: The code sample which you placed already was with quoted name in the function parameter.